# Conditional SQL targeting different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I have a single piece of SQL conditionally change the target server ?

So on my local dev machine, I can run it and have the command ...

```
INSERT  INTO [sds].[dbo].[Team_Email_Addresses]
        SELECT  [class] AS 'Team number' ,
                [description] AS 'Team name' ,
                [DutyEmail] AS 'Team email address'
        FROM    [DEVSERVER].[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]
        WHERE   [status] = 1
```

But on the test machine I want the same piece of SQL to run and have the command ...

```
INSERT  INTO [sds].[dbo].[Team_Email_Addresses]
        SELECT  [class] AS 'Team number' ,
                [description] AS 'Team name' ,
                [DutyEmail] AS 'Team email address'
        FROM    [TESTSERVER].[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]
        WHERE   [status] = 1
```

I've tried using a variable `@TGT` and setting it to either `devserver` or `testserver` with the SQL `FROM    [@TGT].[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]`, but I get an error `Could not find server '@TGT' in sys.servers.`

Comment: Yeap those are the names of the two servers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic SQL. Also you should not be using `'single quotes'` to delimit column aliases; this syntax has been deprecated. You should be using `[square brackets]` or `"double quotes"` (the former generally preferred).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @TGT SYSNAME;

SET @TGT = N'[TESTSERVER]';

SET @sql = N'INSERT  INTO [sds].[dbo].[Team_Email_Addresses]
        SELECT  [class] AS [Team number] ,
                [description] AS [Team name] ,
                [DutyEmail] AS [Team email address]
        FROM    ' + @TGT + '.[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]
        WHERE   [status] = 1;';

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(In fact you don't really need the aliases here, though you should be specifying the insert column list.)

Or, what you can do to make the code more stable, is to use synonyms in your two environments. In dev:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.sp_class FOR DEVSERVER.cases.dbo.sp_class;
```

In Test:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.sp_class FOR TESTSERVER.cases.dbo.sp_class;
```

Now your query can simply be:

```
INSERT  INTO [sds].[dbo].[Team_Email_Addresses]
        SELECT  [class],
                [description],
                [DutyEmail]
        FROM    [dbo].[sp_class]
        WHERE   [status] = 1;
```

Of course synonyms only work if you are on SQL Server 2005 or better. It is always useful to specify the version of SQL Server you are using!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use Synonyms for this kind of situation.  Since you are running this from two different places, you just need to have your synonym defined appropriately in each place.

On your local dev machine:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Cases_sp_class FOR [DEVSERVER].[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]
```

And on your test machine:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.Cases_sp_class FOR [TESTSERVER].[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]
```

Then you would just need to change your SQL to this in all environments:

```
INSERT  INTO [sds].[dbo].[Team_Email_Addresses]
        SELECT  [class] AS 'Team number' ,
                [description] AS 'Team name' ,
                [DutyEmail] AS 'Team email address'
        FROM    [dbo].[Cases_sp_class]
        WHERE   [status] = 1
```

A couple of notes:

1. TESTSERVER and/or DEVSERVER need to be defined as Linked Servers
2. If [sp_class] is really a stored procedure, you will need to do all of this a slightly different way.  If it is not, you should probably not be using the "sp_" prefix for it as that is the prefix that MS uses for it's own system procedures which can get very confusing.

Comment: Obviously I need to type faster, you posted while I was typing and included a nice sample. ;-)

Comment: Tim!  Long time no see!  Well, Aaron actually typed in three diffenet answers (including this one) in the time it took me to get this one in.  Guess that's why he's an MVP ... ;-)

Comment: Thanks but I removed one because I realized that the OP might not have both linked server names set up in both environments, so my UNION idea (and Timothy's IF idea) won't parse in that case.

Comment: Good point, I had blithely assumed that all appropriate linked servers were set up in each environment.

Comment: The `sp_class` is a table ... it's someone else's database, and they don't seem to have any consistency / naming convention for the various artefacts, which does make things a wee bit confusing

Comment: @SteveC: Understood, I've been there myself many times.  Though [sp_class] really is a spectacularly bad name for a table in Sql Server.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron Bertrand points out, Dynamic SQL is one option, and there is a good discussion of dynamic sql at [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

In addition to the dynamic sql option, you could simply include both in an if statement.

```
If <insert condition> then
INSERT  INTO [sds].[dbo].[Team_Email_Addresses]         SELECT  [class] AS 'Team number' ,                 [description] AS 'Team name' ,                 [DutyEmail] AS 'Team email address'         FROM    [DEVSERVER].[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]         WHERE   [status] = 1 
else
INSERT  INTO [sds].[dbo].[Team_Email_Addresses]         SELECT  [class] AS 'Team number' ,                 [description] AS 'Team name' ,                 [DutyEmail] AS 'Team email address'         FROM    [TESTSERVER].[cases].[dbo].[sp_class]         WHERE   [status] = 1
```

And finally, especially if the question condition is based on something like what machine this is running from, you could use a synonym but change what the alias is pointing at on an as needed basis.  This is probably the most complicated option, but it has the advantage of keeping the stored procedures in question shorter and simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately the IF conditional won't parse correctly, even with deferred name resolution, unless both environments have both linked servers set up (which is unlikely).

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  I had blithely assumed that all appropriate linked servers existed.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that article, it's got a lot of interesting pointers on dynamic SQL versus other approaches